# Embedding image binaries in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance

Is there a reason PNG and JPG images would be embedded in a JavaScript file like this:

```
// Template/Image data
var LOGO = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADgAAAA4 etc";

var BACKGROUND = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIA etc";
```

If I remove these portions and call files stored on a server instead, will there be a performance penalty or something?  The only thing I can think of is Apache serving extra requests for those images, but I'm not even sure it works that way.  Is there anything else?

Comment: No particular reason, it's a base64 image, wether it's in the javascript file, the css file or in the HTML doesn't really matter when it comes to performance, it's the same size and the image isn't cached anyway, but the javascript file might be cached. With Base64 there's one request less, but the size of the image is about 1/3 more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its mostly convenience and to avoid preloading the images. Since no additional requests have to be sent to the server to display the image, the image will be displayed as soon as you set this value to the `src` attribute.

In terms of amount of data downloaded, this technique avoids the extra overhead of additional requests but the total sizes downloaded could be a bit larger since the entire image data is encoded in base64. In applications where you might have lots of such images preloading could be a better.

Answer (score 1):

A request to that image file takes longer than showing the image from the binary. So your page has saved some requests :)

Comment: Using this rationale, while isn't this a common practice?  You could theoretically embed all important images into your HTML to save on the number of requests and leave unimportant images out to load later, no?  I just haven't heard of this as a recommended optimization technique.

Comment: But you'd want caching of reused images across pages and across multiple reloads of the same page.

Comment: I usually use this technique for small images like logos and icons.